# Why is my data binding not working properly between Angular Svc, Ctrl, and View?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to pull up in one of my views the information that has already been recorded so I can update it if need be.  I have tried everything that I can think of and the information will not populate in the forms.  When I click on the link it goes to the page with the correct id number for that company but the data does not populate.

Here is my code:

SVC:

```
function getCompany(companyId) {
            return $http.get("api/collections/companies/" + companyId);
        }

function editCompany(company) {
            $http.put("api/collections/companies/" + company._id, company).then(function (res) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast("company:updated");
                $log.info("company:updated");
            });

        }
```

Ctrl:

```
companiesSvc.getCompany($routeParams.companyId).success(function (company) {
          $timeout(function () {
            $scope.company = company;
          });
        });

$scope.editCompany = function (company) {
            console.log(company);
            companiesSvc.editCompany(company).then(function () {
              $location.path('/admin/companies');
            });
        };
```

View:

```
<form ng-submit="editCompany(company)">
  <input type="text" data-ng-model="company.title" value="company.title"><br>
  <input type="text" data-ng-model="company.url" value="company.url"><br>
  <input type="text" data-ng-model="company.location" value="company.location"><br>
  <input type="text" data-ng-model="company.phoneNumber" value="company.phoneNumber"><br>
  <input type="email" data-ng-model="company.email" value="company.email"><br>
  <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" data-ng-model="company.technologies" value="company.technologies">{{company.technologies}}</textarea><br>
  <button type="submit">Update</button>
  <a href="#/admin/companies"><button>Cancel</button></a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are updating the scope with an asynchronous function (right?), I'd guess you need to make use of $timeout (which will need to become a dependency of your controller).

```
$timeout(function() {
    $scope.company = company;
});
```

Comment: I tried wrapping it in $timeout and it still is not doing the trick.  That does sound like something that should work though.  I have updated the original question with the new code.

Comment: Can you just alert or console.log to verify your success callback is actually being called?

Comment: Looking at this again, I'd also be logging your 'company' object to make sure it's structured the way you are expecting as well.